# Django. Как в {% static ... %} поместить {{ ... }}

Tags: python, django

делаю сайт на django и появилась проблема в том, что в {% %} логики django нужно поместить {{ car.href }} - ссылку на изображение из базы данных.

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'mainApp/slider/{{ car.href }}' %}" alt='{{ car.alt }}'>
```

Как поместить {{ }} в {% %}. Код выше выдает /static/mainApp/slider/%7B%7B%20car.href%20%7D%7D вот такую ссылку на изображение.

Comment: Если это вам понадобилось, значит вы неправильно используете статику. Статика должна быть статичной.

Comment: Это нужно, чтоб из админ-панели можно было быстро изменить одно изображение на другое, без редактирования кода. Все изображения, как были в папке static так и будут.

Comment: Тем более нужно использовать media.

Comment: Если вам нужна возможность загружать новые картинки через админку, то static для этого абсолютно точно не подходит (static потому и называется static, что не меняется никогда), а для этого нужно использовать media

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно в вашем случае не вижу никаких предпосылок, чтобы помещать переменную внутрь тега `static`. Чтобы получить валидный url, достаточно:

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'mainApp/slider/' %}{{ car.href }}" alt='{{ car.alt }}'>
```

Так же хотелось прояснить немного комментарии под вашим вопросом. Есть одно золотое правило: если изображения загружает пользователь, то в целях безопасности их ложат в media, но никак не в статик. Если же эти изображения являются постоянными и не планируется их менять в процессе работы сайта, то допустим `static`

Comment: Если уж использовать костыли, так хоть подходящие - [get_static_prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , можно и `get_static_prefix`. Но разве у них не одинаковый результат будет?